# Set index of an array as a variable

Tags: php, web

Sorry, but it might be a very simple answer.

I do have an array:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 0 )
```

If I do this:

```
foreach($array as $key){
    $index = $key;
    print_r($index);
}
```

Of course I get:

3

0

I want to have a variable with the index:

0

1

How do I do it? It should be very simple. I am disparing! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
foreach(array_keys($array) as $key) {
   $value = $array[$key];
}
```

Comment: In your first suggestion. What do I have to type to get the index-position?

Comment: $key will be the array index that's currently being evaluated (your 0, 1, etc...). Either version gives you the same value.

Comment: No $key is returning 3 and 0. Not the index 0 & 1.  I want the postion of 3 and 0, so I want 0 & 1 in the foreach-loop. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, and what I've suggested would work. The `$key => $val` construct gets you both the array's keys (0,1,...) and the values (3,0,...). If you've got non-consecutive keys, then you'll have to count the position yourself.

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the index? If I do foreach($array as $key=>$val){print_r($key);} I get 3 and 0, not the index 0 and 1. But I need this loop foreach($array as $key=>$val). How do I count the position? Thanks a lot!

Comment: LIke you said, do `foreach ($array as $key => $val)`. It has to be in that order. If you do `$val => $key` all you've done is change the NAMES of the variables. PHP doesn't care what the name of the two vars are, it'll put the index values into the var BEFORE the `=>` and the value into the variable AFTER the `=>`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
  print $key;
}
```

...or use [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of the foreach() statement, the following returns the array keys and values.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo $key.' => '.$value;  // Outputs 0 => 3, 1 => 0
}
```

`$key` is the array *key* (or *index*) ie. 0 and 1. `$value` is the *value* for the corresponding array `$key` ie. 3 and 0.

The other format of the foreach() statement is what you have in your question and returns just the array *values* (although you call this `$key` in your code), so...

```
foreach($array as $value){
    echo $value;  // Outputs 3, 0
}
```